# Math: Pallet Packing (not quite the bin-packing situation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, pseudocode, bin-packing

I'm currently working on some private project on my spare time, and I've been stuck on a particular math problem.

I know that bin packing is a NP-HARD problem, but that's not exactly the problem I'm facing here.

What I must do is to calculate the number of pallets I would need to fit the given number of boxes, however the layout (of first/base level) is defined in advance. For me, the problem is that I have to take the box weight, pallet max weight, box height and pallet max height into consideration. In one moment it sounds like an elementary school math, but then I suddenly get lost with too many `if` and `else` statements.

The following is what I have:

Pallet (width, depth, max. height, max. weight)

Box ( total number of boxes, width, depth, height, weight)

Now, as I mentioned, the easy part is that I already know in advance how many boxes can I fit on a first layer. But then, I get lost because I'm trying to check too many things.

In example, the pallet can reach it's max weight before the max height is filled (and vice versa). Another (improbable but possible) scenario, the total number of boxes (if small enough) can be fitted on a single pallet without reaching the pallet's max height/weight.

In the end, I need to know the number of fully loaded pallets and if any boxes left for the last (partially filled) pallet.

I'm currently working in `javascript`. I'd be grateful if anyone can help me with with this, at least with some pseudo code that I can convert.

If you're willing to give it a shot, here are some numbers you can run your algorithm against:

```
Box Values:
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Width(cm) | Depth(cm) | Height(cm) | Weight(kg) | Fits(single layer) | Total (number of) |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|      32.5 |        24 |         22 |       14.7 |                  9 |               111 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+

Pallet Values:
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| Width(cm) | Depth(cm) | Max.Height(cm) | Max.Weight(cm) |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|       120 |        80 |            145 |            725 |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

EDIT:
I apologize for being unclear. I was lost in my own calculations. I updated the given values.

Also, I forgot to mention that the pallets are loaded to fill max in both weight and height. So, there can also be a partially filled layer on top (in case that max height isn't filled with previous layers and one more filled layer would go over allowed max weight).

Comment: If "_the layout (of first/base level) is defined in advance_" is true, why you provided `Width` and `Depth` in your example? For fixed layout all we need is `NumberOfBoxesInSingleLayer` (and its value is actually not obvious from your example because if you rotate boxes you can fit `5x2` = `10` boxes but without rotation you can fit only `3x3` = `9` boxes in a single layer.)

Comment: The problem description is a little unclear to me; at the moment the solution seems fairly trivial: since the number and hence total weight of boxes above a certain layer is always known, one can always minimize the height and thus number of pallets to be added next by greedily fitting as many boxes as possible on each layer after the first. ... Unless either of us has missed something?

Comment: @SergGr Yes, you're right, I calculate `NumberOfBoxesInSingleLayer` before entering the pallet function, so the `Width` and `Depth` are not needed here. While my calculation doesn't solve the bin packing problem, it serves my purpose OK.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Partially, you're right. I've just updated my question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @cobster doesn't your edit pretty much exactly describe the situation in my comment?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog pretty much :)

Comment: I mean, doesn't the method in my comment exactly solve this problem, i.e. it is in-fact pretty trivial?

Comment: @cobster, to restate  meowgoesthedog, where do you see the problem with implementation of the method described in the second comment?

Comment: @SergGr Practically from the start. As I see it, I can go in two directions: 1) see how many layers can I fit in `maxHeight` and then go check if it exceeds the `maxWeight`. If it does, remove one layer and fill that partial layer box by box until  `maxWeight` is filled.

Comment: 2) is the opposite of 1) - take weight of single layer and see how many of them fit the `maxWeight`. Then go check if they exceed the `maxHeight` etc... Which 'path' would be better?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the code that I think embodies what meowgoesthedog meant:

```
function fillPallets(totalBoxNumber, boxHeight, boxWeight, boxesPerLayer, palletMaxHeight, palletMaxWeight) {
    let maxBoxesByHeight = Math.floor(palletMaxHeight / boxHeight) * boxesPerLayer;
    let maxBoxesByWeight = Math.floor(palletMaxWeight / boxWeight);
    let maxBoxesPerPallet = Math.min(maxBoxesByHeight, maxBoxesByWeight);
    let fullPalletsCount = Math.floor(totalBoxNumber / maxBoxesPerPallet);
    let palletsCount = Math.ceil(totalBoxNumber / maxBoxesPerPallet);
    let lastPalletBoxes = totalBoxNumber - fullPalletsCount * maxBoxesPerPallet;
    let buildPallet = function (number) {
        let palletLayers = [];
        for (let rest = number; rest > 0; rest -= boxesPerLayer) {
            palletLayers.push(Math.min(rest, boxesPerLayer))
        }
        return palletLayers;
    }
    let pallets = [];
    let fullPallet = buildPallet(maxBoxesPerPallet);
    for (let i = 0; i < fullPalletsCount; i++) {
        pallets.push(fullPallet);
    }
    if (lastPalletBoxes > 0)
        pallets.push(buildPallet(lastPalletBoxes));

    return {
        count: palletsCount,
        palletsLayouts: pallets
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
fillPallets(111,22,14.7,9,145,725)
```

produces following output

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "palletsLayouts": [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4], [9, 4]]
}
```

The idea behind this code is that you want to calculate  `maxBoxesPerPallet` and there are only two independent restrictions on that: either height or weight. So you calculate `maxBoxesByHeight` and `maxBoxesByWeight` first, then you get `maxBoxesPerPallet`, then you get the number of pallets (most of them will be "full" i.e. contain exactly `maxBoxesPerPallet` and there might be one last for the rest).